# Finding duplicates with pointers

Tags: c, string, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int *num=malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
    int n,dup=0;
    printf("Enter number of elements");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter numbers");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
            scanf("%d",num+i);

    }

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=1;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(*(num+i)==*(num+j))
            {
                    dup++;
            }

         }
         }

    printf("%d",dup);
    free(num);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to find the number of times an element is repeated,using pointers.But I'm not getting the right output.What's wrong with this code?
Edit: for inputs 1,2,3 I'm getting an output of 2.

Comment: Please [edit]  your question and show a simple example of input and expected output.

Comment: "I'm not getting the right output" is not a very helpful description of the problem. What output do you expect to get, and how does the output you are actually observing differ from it?

Comment: OT: but you should fix the indentation of your code, which is not consistent.

Comment: OT: BTW I'd advise against using pointers here other than for exercise, unless you think `*(num+i)` is more readable than `num[i]`. Same for `num+i` vs `&num[i]`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky that is the question premise: "using pointers".

Answer (score 2):

The inner loop is wrong and repeating pairs

```
for(int j = 1; j < n; j++)
```

change it to

```
for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
```

You should also move the `malloc` line further down and base it on the input;

```
int *num = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
```

Comment: This fixed the issue.But if I'm initializing j at 1, shouldn't it be one step ahead of i always?

Comment: No, not when `i` is 3. `j` is then less.

Comment: Okay got it.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If `i` and `j` are the same, you'll always get a match.  You'll also get duplicate matches if for example elements 2 and 3 match because you check 2 against 3 and 3 against 2.  To catch that, start `j` at one more than `i` instead of 1.  Also, you'll want to break out of the inner loop when you find a duplicate so that if there are multiple instances you don't count them more than once.

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
    {
        if (*(num+i)==*(num+j))
        {
                dup++;
                break;
        }
     }
 }
```